# How do I search for a row where the value is not defined?

Tags: mysql

I have a table ID, Loc, Code, Value

```
ID | Loc  | Code | Value    
1  | USA  | 1    | A
2  | NUS  | 2    | B
3  | NA   | 1    | C    
4  | NA   | 2    | D
```

If I pass in loc = USA, it should return me 1 (which it does), if pass in loc = NUS, it should return me 2 (which it does), if I pass any other value (e.g, AUS, LON) it should return me 3 & # which it does not. How do I write a query that does it all.

Thanks!

Comment: Why should it do that?

Comment: You need to show the code. I assume by `3 & #` you meant `3 and 4`?

Comment: If you search `WHERE Loc = 'NA'` you should get 3 and 4.

Comment: The query is for if the location is sent as USA then return row 1, if it is sent as NUS then return 2, else for any other values return 3 & 4

Comment: why 3??? why not 4???

Comment: I meant rows 3 & 4 as they do not match USA & NUS

Answer (score 0):

I think you can you `CASE` here in a similar way like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
  CASE WHEN Loc = 'USA' THEN ID
    WHEN Loc = 'NUS' THEN ID
    ELSE (
        SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(ID SEPARATOR ' & ') 
        FROM test 
        WHERE Loc != 'USA' AND Loc != 'NUS'
    )
    END
) AS result
FROM test
WHERE Loc = 'NA';
```

Result ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13fc5/5))

```
3 & 4 & 7
```

EDIT:

Separate id values

```
SELECT DISTINCT (
  CASE WHEN Loc = 'USA' THEN ID
    WHEN Loc = 'NUS' THEN ID
    ELSE (
        SELECT ID
    )
    END
) AS result
FROM test
WHERE Loc = 'NA';
```

Result ([SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13fc5/10))

Comment: This does not return the rows based on location.  I expect it to take a location (eg. USA or AUS and return the respective rows. (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13fc5/4/0)

Comment: Ok, edited to return rows based on location. I think that this solution is what you want.

Comment: Any chance I can get the rows returned rather than a concatenated single value

Comment: Kostas.. Really appreciate the help.  But when I put in a different location (e.g. AUS), I expect rows 3 & 4 to be returned. It returns nothing.  (http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/13fc5/11)

Comment: This is because the value 'IND' you have in WHERE clause doesn't exist in the data set of the table.